# webpack bundle typescript to ts-loader but get module is not defined on browser?

Tags: typescript, webpack, ts-loader

[follow webpack typescript doc](https://webpack.js.org/guides/typescript/)

when i use webpack ts-loader to convert typescript it's can't work cause module is not defined?

but when i just command tsc, this result can work on browser

also this issues is already use gulp to fix

but gulp use browserify to transform typescript

so i want to use webpack to bundle my express server and client typescript!

why webpack ts-loader to transform typescript get "module is not defined" on browser?

[this repositories on github](https://github.com/Frenkieli/expressBasic)

webpack.config.js

```
const nodeeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');
const path = require('path');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

const serverConfig = {
  target: 'node',
  devtool: 'eval-source-map',
  node: {
    __dirname: false,
    __filename: true,
  },
  externals: [nodeExternals()],
  entry: {
    'index': './src/index.js',
    // 'public/javascripts/temibroad': './src/client/typescript/temibroad/temibroad.ts'
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs2',
  },
  module: {   //設定你的檔案選項
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: 'babel-loader'
      }
    ],
  },
  // plugins: [
  //   new CopyWebpackPlugin([
  //     { from: 'src/client/views', to: 'views' },
  //     { from: 'src/client/static', to: 'public' },
  //   ])
  // ],
  optimization: {
    minimize: true,
  }
}

const clientConfig = {
  target: 'web',
  devtool: 'eval-source-map',
  node: {
    __dirname: false,
    __filename: true,
  },
  externals: [nodeExternals()],
  entry: {
    // 'index': './src/index.js',
    'public/javascripts/temibroad': './src/client/typescript/temibroad/temibroad.ts'
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs2',
  },
  module: {   //設定你的檔案選項
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: 'babel-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        use: 'ts-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [ '.tsx', '.ts', '.js' ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([
      { from: 'src/client/views', to: 'views' },
      { from: 'src/client/static', to: 'public' },
    ])
  ],
  optimization: {
    minimize: true,
  }
}



module.exports = [serverConfig, clientConfig];
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
  "target": "es5",
  "module": "commonjs",
  "sourceMap": true,
  "noEmitOnError" : false,
  "strict": true,
  "noImplicitAny": true,
  "strictNullChecks": true,
  "esModuleInterop": true,
  "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mh...i know why got "module is not defined" on browser, cause my output library setting.

When my project done, then I research webpack doc, step by step check my setting, i find why i setting "commonjs2"(2??) on browser?

Commonjs can't work on browser immediately, so when i setting libraryTarget to "var", also setting library:'myLibrary' to call TS function, problem is solved.

Check out the settings below

```
/* webpack.config.js ： Webpack 的設定檔 */
// const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');

const clientConfig = {
  target: 'web',
  devtool: 'eval-source-map',
  entry: {
    // 'index': './src/index.js',
    'index': './src/index.ts'
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    library :'aaa',
    libraryTarget: 'var'
  },
  module: {   //設定你的檔案選項
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        use: 'ts-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [ '.tsx', '.ts', '.js' ],
  },
}

module.exports = [clientConfig];
```

index.ts

```
import { gogogo } from './import';


gogogo();

export { gogogo };

console.log('你好');
```

import.ts

```
function gogogo(str = 'gogogog'){
  console.log(str);
}

export {gogogo};
```

index.html

```
<script src="./dist/index.bundle.js"></script>
<script>
  console.log(aaa);
  aaa.gogogo('外面傳入');
</script>
```

Browser Console

```
gogogog             import.ts?661f:6
好                  index.ts?71bd:7
{__esModule: true}  index.html:11 
外面傳入             import.ts?661f:6
```

update on 2020/06/30 with require.js

webpack.config.js

```
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    // library :'aaa',
    libraryTarget: 'amd'
  },
```

index.html

```
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.3.6/require.min.js'></script>
  <script>
    require(['./dist/index.bundle'], function(aaa){
      console.log(aaa);
      aaa.gogogo('from aaa');
    })
  </script>
```

Comment: Hello, I such with this, this is working perfectly for me in browser though I also want to use it like var aaa  = require("<my package>");  aaa.gogogo('外面傳入'); but unfortunately it doesnot work with require, do you have any idea / suggestion to do it.

Comment: I thought on browser the "require" is require.js, so change webpack config " libraryTarget: 'amd' ", could see on my update content.